# 404 error when using Laravel PHPUnit press() function

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am trying to run phpunit on a development environment. However, whenever I have a function that utilizes the press() function, I get a 404 error.

```
1) LoginTest::testLoginWithInvalidCredentials  
A request to [http://localhost/set/public/auth/login] failed. Received status code [404].

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\set\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\InteractsWithPages.php:165 
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\set\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\InteractsWithPages.php:63 
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\set\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\InteractsWithPages.php:85 
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\set\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\InteractsWithPages.php:658 
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\set\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\InteractsWithPages.php:645 
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\set\tests\LoginTest.php:49

Caused by exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\set\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php:161
```

When I access http://localhost/set/public/auth/login, the URL works fine. In fact, when I utilize the site, everything works. Also, if I run the phpunit on my local machine, I don't get the error at all.

I have checked over my .env file and everything checks out for the system to work. And my routes seem correct as well. If I manually run the test, everything performs correctly. It is just running this phpunit test that fails.

Any direction as to where to look would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class LoginTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseTransactions;

    public function testLoginPageOk()
    {
        $this->visit('/')           
           ->see('You are accessing');
    }

    public function testRedirectToLoginPage()
    {
        $this->call('GET','/');
        $this->assertRedirectedTo('auth/login');

   }

    public function testAuthLoginRoutes()
    {
        $this->call('GET', '/auth/login');
        $this->see('You are accessing');
    }

    public function testLoginWithInvalidCredentials()
    {
        $this->visit('/auth/login')
            ->type('asdf', 'username')
            ->type('gibberish', 'password')
            ->press('Sign in')
            ->see('These credentials do not match our records.');
    }
}
```

Here is my routes file:

```
<?php 

// This group requires a user to be logged in.
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {

    // when you login, if you were not going to a page, you get directed 
    // to /home. Let's push that to the actual home page.
    Route::get('home', function(){ return redirect('/');});

    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
});

// Authentication routes. Doesn't need to be logged in.
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
```

And finally my .env file is as follows:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=ycDUbCfgo81OJfc1TjNBjggAtXqwES5I
APP_URL=http://localhost/set/public/

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=ilsausmail
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: Turns out it is the code inside my login form.

I had it as:

```
action="/auth/login"
```

However, I was not running laravel on the root domain, but rather in a few directories deep. Once I fixed it to the following it worked.

```
action="{{ url('/auth/login') }}"
```